# Why are two identical strings not testing as equal?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, compare

My code:

```
stringFromRecievedData =
    [[NSString alloc]initWithData:_data1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

if (![stringFromRecievedData isEqualToString:lastStringFromRecievedData]) {
    [lastStringFromRecievedData setString: stringFromRecievedData];
```

I get the same "not equal" result even in the second round- even when it is the same data each time...

Is this the correct way to compare the two?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show where and how you are defining `lastStringFromReceivedData`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `lastStringFromRecievedData` is an instance of `NSString` (or subclass such as `NSMutableString`), then this is the correct way to compare two strings. In this case something else may be causing your strings to not be equal.

However, it looks like `lastStringFromRecievedData` is a some other object because you are calling `setString:` on it. If this is the case, you need to get the string from that object first.

```
stringFromRecievedData =
    [[NSString alloc]initWithData:_data1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// Assuming 'string' is the function to get the string from 'setString:' below
NSString *otherString = [lastStringFromRecievedData string];

if (![stringFromRecievedData isEqualToString:otherString]) {
    [lastStringFromRecievedData setString: stringFromRecievedData];
```

Comment: lastStringFromRecievedData is NSMutableString- 
So you suggest using [lastStringFromRecievedData string]?

Comment: No, if it is an `NSMutableString` then the comparison should work. What kind of data is in these strings?

Comment: The Data is  from a web response, 
The only way I get this to work is if I am using a scanner on the received string to scan it into a new string-
in that case the comparison succeeds.
I thought there is something about the string format?

Comment: Maybe I will try using absoluteString  on the recieved string?
[lastStringFromRecievedData absoluteString]

Comment: Yes- at log they are exactly the same.
This is also why I suspect that there is somthing to do with the fact that this string is created from Data.
[[NSString alloc]initWithData:_data1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
_data1 is just the data I recieve as a responce to connection request.
I tried many things, the only thing that worked for me was to scan the string into a new string using a scanner.
Maybe this is what I will do- But I hoped to understand this issue...

Comment: What happens if you loop through all the characters in each string and compare the individual characters? (using `characterAtIndex:`)

Comment: Thank you- I have found that there is a difference between them- It was 1 different char in a very long string so I have not seen it...

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing is looking to make sure your `NSMutableString` is equivalent to another `NSString`, why not do something like:

```
lastStringFromRecievedData = [stringFromRecievedData mutableCopy];
```

Or:

```
[lastStringFromRecievedData setString:stringFromRecievedData];
```

The end result will be the same.

Comment: What you wrote is exactly what I did from the first-place.
Re-read the question - The issue is when I recreate  stringFromRecievedData and try to find out if they are equal-
If they are not- it means I recieved new Data.
Both strings are Identical on the log- but I get a resault that they not equal- this is the issue.

Comment: I am getting a String from Data and my purpose is to find out if I already got this string before or not.